# Genymotion and Android Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, genymotion

I'm using IntelliJ for Android development. I'm using this project as a test project to make android app run on Genymotion:

https://github.com/nicokruger/android-maven-phonegap

I am able to run

```
$mvn android:dex
$mvn android:apk
```

However

`$mvn android:emulator-start` fails

```
[INFO] Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] Starting android emulator with script: /tmp/android-maven-plugin-emulator-start.sh
[INFO] Waiting for emulator start:5000
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.673 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-01T11:48:03+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:emulator-start (default-cli) on project test: MojoExecutionException: Timeout while waiting for emulator to startup. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is not meant to run non-SDK emulator. Plugin search for emulator executable under following path (as it can be found in code):

```
String emulatorPath = new File ( 
    getAndroidSdk().getToolsPath(), parsedExecutable ).getAbsolutePath();
```